# Regex to parse string between two markers without capture groups and excluding markers

Tags: c#, regex

With a collection of string as so:

```cs
string s1 = "   Identifier1 = Value1                      ## Comment";
string s2 = "   Something = SomeData";
string s3 = "   Name = information\\t\\t\\t## More comments!";
string s4 = "   Nam2 = information";
```

I need a regex pattern that will grab all of the information on the line after the equals-sign (=) up to either the end of the line OR the ## comment marker, but NOT capture either of them.

Giving me (respectively):

```
" Value1                      "
" SomeData"
" information\\t\\t\\t"
" information"
```

I've come up with this so far: `(?<=[=]).+(?=(?>##|$))`

It kind of works, insofar as it manages to grab all text after the = sign until the end of the string, but it never works when there's a comment marker: ## as it still grabs until the end of the string, instead of stopping at the ##.

...and if I change the pattern to: `(?<=[=]).+(?=##))`

Then it *only* works on lines with comment markers (and stops before them as desired).

So what am I doing wrong/missing to get it to end the capture either just before ## OR at EOL? Also, I can't use explicit or implicit capturing groups as these patterns are passed into a parser that turns them into non-capturing groups when it processes them.

I've never used look-ahead/behind patterns until just the past few days and this stuff is breaking my brain...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex (as seen in use [here](https://regex101.com/r/O1mtEe/1)):

```
(?<==)(?:(?!#{2}).)*
```

- `(?<==)` lookbehind ensuring what precedes matches `=` literally
- `(?:(?!#{2}).)*` matches any character (excludes newline) any number of times until it reaches `##`

  - This is called a [tempered greedy token](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37343088/3600709)

Comment: Okay, well, it definitely works! Though I'm still trying to work out how/why!
(Also, thanks for the link! Now that I know what it's called, I'm actually finding assistance references about it. Without knowing that term I was totally hitting brick walls trying to search for a sol'n!)

Answer (score 2):

You can use this regex,

```
(?<==).*?(?=#{2}|$)
```

**Explanation:**

- `(?<==)` - Positive look behind to ensure matched text is preceded by `=`
- `.*?` - This matches any text in non-greedy way
- `(?=#{2}|$)` - Positive look ahead to ensure matched text is followed by either `##` or end of line `$`

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/WXVzbU/2)**